# shell_exec not executing command in php

Tags: php, winscp

I'm trying to run this command from a windows computer, but I can't get it to work. The command works perfectly when I enter it into command prompt, but not when I execute the PHP script.

```
$command = '"C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\winscp.exe" /console /command "open client" "cd /var/www/html/reports" "put C:\wamp\www\client\test.php" "exit"';
shell_exec($command);
```

Comment: are you sure, that the method is not forbidden? And are you sure, that the parameters are escaped correctly?

Comment: Are you running Apache or whatever server you use as a service? If you're on Windows, the server is forbidden to interact with the system unless it has special permission or is opened as a normal process.

Comment: Check `safe_mode` and `disable_functions`. http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php

Also, start with just one command (e.g. running winscp).

Comment: I use shell_exec elsewhere in the application and it works fine. And I checked disable_functions, there is nothing listed there.

Comment: Add `/log` switch and inspect the log. You also want to use `winscp.com`, not `winscp.exe`. See http://winscp.net/eng/docs/executables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `exec()` it can help you do debugging.

```
<?php
$command = '"C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\winscp.exe" /console /command "open client" "cd /var/www/html/reports" "put C:\wamp\www\client\test.php" "exit"';
$cmd = exec($command, $arr, $opt);

// Output info run from the command:
var_dump($cmd, $arr, $opt);
```

Comment: I got from this the ouput: string(0) "" array(0) { } int(1)

Comment: It looks like you are running more than one command, you need to separate them, I don't remember how, but I think it is with the `&` command: http://superuser.com/questions/62850/execute-multiple-commands-with-1-line-in-windows-commandline